# Swift how does my function exceed O(n)?

Tags: swift, algorithm

I am trying to work on a leetcode problem that asks for

> Given an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once.
>
> Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this array.

My solution to the problem is:

```
func findDisappearedNumbers(_ nums: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var returnedArray = [Int]()

    if nums.isEmpty == false {
        for i in 1...nums.count {
            if nums.contains(i) == false {
                returnedArray.append(i)
            }
        }
    } else {
        returnedArray = nums
    }
    return returnedArray
}
```

However, leetcode tells me that my solution is "Time limit exceeded"

Shouldn't my solution be O(n)? I am not sure where did I made it to be greater than O(n).

Comment: `nums.contains(i)` is O(n), and you have this embedded into a `for` which is also O(n), thus => O(n^2)

Comment: @Cristik no wonder! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I haven't missed anything your algorithm is O(n^2).

First, you iterate over each element of the array which is O(n), but for each element, you call `contains` which has to iterate over all the elements again and you end up with O(n^2).

I refrain from telling you the solution since it is for leetcode.

Comment: no wonder! Thank you for your help!! (and yes please dont telling me the answer!!)